# Como crear tabla con rowspan de 2 niveles en los td Agular9

Tags: html, json, angular9

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que ordenar la tabla por niveles, ordene mi json con los datos:
Nivel1 y sus hijos Nivel2 y los hijos Nivel3, es decir el Nivel3 depende de Nivel2 y este depende de Nivel 1.
Logre hacer algo con Angular1 con ng-repeat pero no logre hacer el rowspan dinamico lo cual supongo es necesario. En el sistema que estoy dando soporte es necesario trabajar con Angular9 y este usa *ngFor llevo ya varios días varado en esto gracias de antemano.

Como lo muestro a continuación cada objeto del json tiene un objeto hijos[] nivel2 y este tiene a su vez otro objeto hijos[] nivel3, recorriendo así tres niveles.

```js
//Interfaces 
interface hijos2 {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  mark: string;
  hijos:hijos3[];
}
interface hijos3 {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  mark: string;
}
interface Niveles {
    nivel: string;
    name: string;
    hijos: hijos2[];
}

//El construccion de los datos
  const NIVELES: Niveles[]  = [
  {
    nivel: 'nivel-1',
    name: 'Nombre1 nivel1',
    hijos: [
      {
        name: 'Nombre1 nivel2',
        type: '1nivel2',
        mark: 'Sony',
        hijos:[
          {  
            name: 'Nombre1 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },         
          {   
            name: 'Nombre2 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3.1',
            mark: 'Sony'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Nombre2 nivel2',
        type: '2nivel2',
        mark: 'Sony',
        hijos:[
          {   
            name: 'Nombre1 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },
          {   
            name: 'Nombre2 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3.1',
            mark: 'Sony'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    nivel: 'nivel-1',
    name: 'Nombre2 nivel1',
    hijos: [
      {
        name: 'Nombre1 nivel2',
        type: '1nivel2',
        mark: 'Sony',
        hijos:[
          {  
            name: 'Nombre1 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },
          {  
            name: 'Nombre2 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },
          {  
            name: 'Nombre3 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },
          {  
            name: 'Nombre4 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Nombre2 nivel2',
        type: '2nivel2',
        mark: 'Sony',
        hijos:[
          {   
            name: 'Nombre1 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3',
            mark: 'Sony'
          },
          {   
            name: 'Nombre2 nivel3',
            type: 'Computer3.1',
            mark: 'Sony'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export class NgbdTableBasic {
  niveles = NIVELES;
}
```

Html

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Nivel1</th>
        <th>Nivel2</th>
        <th>Nivel3</th>
        <th>Otros datos Nivel3</th>
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let p of pessoas; index as i">
        <td rowspan="4">{{p.name}}      
          <td rowspan="2">{{p.hijos[0].name}}   
            <td>{{p.hijos[0].hijos[0].name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.hijos[0].hijos[0].mark}}</td>
            <tr *ngFor="let n3 of p.hijos[$index].hijos; index as i">

    </tbody>
</table>

Esto lo estaba haciendo en Angular1,con el rowspan quemado, no logre hacerlo dinámico
<tr *ngFor="let p of niveles; index as i">
        <td rowspan="4">{{p.name}}      
          <td rowspan="2">{{p.hijos[0].name}}   
            <td>{{p.hijos[0].hijos[0].name}}</td>
            <td>{{p.hijos[0].hijos[0].mark}}</td>            
            <tr *ngFor="let n3  of p.hijos[j].hijos; index as j">
              <td>{{n3.name}}</td>
              <td>{{n3.mark}}  </td>
            </tr>
          </td>
          <tr ng-repeat="n2 in p.hijos" ng-if="$index &gt; 0">
            <td rowspan="{{(2)}}">{{n2.name}}  
              <td>{{n2.hijos[0].name}}</td>
              <td>{{n2.hijos[0].mark}}
                <tr ng-repeat="n3 in p.hijos[$index].hijos" ng-if="$index &gt; 0">
                  <td>{{n3.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{n3.mark}}</td>
                </tr>
              </td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </td>
      </tr>
```